# mail not being received with python SMTP

Tags: python, email, smtp

Hello I am trying to make python 3 send a simple email from Ubuntu.

I started a simple smpt server with:
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025

The following is the code for my email server:

```
import smtplib

message = """
Hello
"""
sender = "dancbtalk@yahoo.com"
receivers=["dancbtalk@yahoo.com"]
try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 1025)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

My output says that the email is send successfully but when I actually check that email account, it has received nothing.  I have tried this with several email accounts.

Comment: Hi , I am facing a similar issue. Were you able to get the solution . Did the below answer solve your problem? Please share your solution.

Answer (score 4):

Your message does not have any headers. Or more precisely, your message contains *only* headers, none of which will be recognized as valid. At the very least you probably want to add Subject, From, and To headers.  E.g.

```
sender    = "dancbtalk@yahoo.com"
receivers = ["dancbtalk@yahoo.com"]

headers = f"""From: {sender}
To: {", ".join(receivers)}
Subject: Hello
"""

message = headers + "\n" + """
Hello
"""
```