# Sending a dict from a list as a Gmail

Tags: python, email, selenium

I want the script to email any objects in the newProperties list.  Each object in the list is like so:

```
  newProperties[0] = {"marketing_package_url": "http://www.capitalpacific.com/inquiry/TrailsEndMarketplaceExecSummary.pdf", "location": "OREGON CITY, OR", "title": "TRAILS END MARKETPLACE", "contact": "mailto:mhorwitz@capitalpacific.com"}   \

 newProperties[1] = {"marketing_package_url": "http://cp.capitalpacific.com/Properties/Yukon-Village-YukonOK.pdf", "location": "YUKON, OK", "title": "YUKON VILLAGE", "contact": "mailto:rsanner@capitalpacific.com"}

...
```

/ full script

```
from selenium import webdriver
import smtplib
import sys
import re
import json

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#Capital Pacific Website
#Commerical Real Estate

#open text file containing property titles we already know about
#list q contains unique marketing URLS we already know about 
oldProperties = []
p = re.compile(r'https?:\/\/[^"]+', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
with(open("properties.txt", "rU")) as f:
    for line in f:
        q = re.findall(p, line)
        oldProperties.extend(q)

#search for new listings
driver.get("http://cp.capitalpacific.com/Properties")

#all listing on current page get put into this list
newProperties = []

for property in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('table.property div.property'):
    title = property.find_element_by_css_selector('div.title h2')
    location = property.find_element_by_css_selector('div.title h4')
    marketing_package = property.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Marketing Package')
    contact_email = property.find_element_by_partial_link_text('.com')


    newProperties.append({
        'title': title.text,
        'location': location.text,
        'marketing_package_url': marketing_package.get_attribute("href"),
        'contact': contact_email.get_attribute("href")
    })

driver.close()

#find the properties that we already have by cross referencing the
#marketing URLS
for x in oldProperties:
    for item in newProperties:
        if (item['marketing_package_url'] == x):
            newProperties.remove(item)


#properties now has only the new properties
#add them to the file
with open('properties.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for item in newProperties:
        json.dump(item, outfile)


#if no new properties found, terminate script
#else, email properties
#if no new properties found, terminate script
#else, email properties
if len(newProperties) == 0:
    sys.exit()
else: 
    fromaddr = 'osxxxxxt@gmail.com'
    toaddrs = ['osfsfsar@onid.oregonstate.edu']
    username = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
    password = '0fdrfdf'

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)

    for item in newProperties:
        msg = str(item) #PROBLEM HERE
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)

    server.quit()
```

The problem is the emails currently sent are empty.  I used str(item) in order to send any new listings on the page, but it seems to be having an issue making the dict into a string and then sending it.  Does anybody know how I could fix this?

Comment: You're not including any headers with your message. At the very least you're going to want From, To, Subject, and maybe MIME-Type. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214097/mail-not-being-received-with-python-smtp/24214198#24214198

Comment: Which part of your code is [tag:Selenium]?

Comment: @SiKing added full code.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear - I am sorry. Are you having problems sending mail with Selenium, or sending mail with SMTP library? If you want serious answers to your problem, have a careful read through this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve